# What happened to NetBeans versions comparison table?

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, versions, system-requirements

There used to be on the web (perhaps on the NetBeans web site) a table that displayed, for several recent major versions of NetBeans, what minimum JDK was required AND what maximum version of Tomcat was supported, and maybe the JSP and/or JEE version supported.  Now I can't find that table anywhere, and it was very useful.  Does such a document still exist anywhere?  If this is not the right forum to post in, can you please direct me where I should?

Thanks,

Rebeccah

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it was never a netbeans comparison table.  It was a tomcat comparison table, and it's currently here:
[Tomcat's version comparison table](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)